# How to hide legend box in pyside6

Tags: python, pyside6

[image: I have a graph here in QtGraphs]

However, removing setName only makes the legend name disappear. using `chart.legend().hide()` makes the chart axis disappear as well.

I do not see a hide function in the documentation.

Here is my code.

```
        # Add Federal Reserve Data
        unemployment_data = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({u'2012-06-08': 388,
 u'2012-06-09': 388,
 u'2012-06-10': 388,
 u'2012-06-11': 389,
 u'2012-06-12': 389,
 u'2012-07-05': 392,
 u'2012-07-06': 392}, orient='index', columns=['foo'])
        self.unemployment_chart = QLineSeries()
        for date, value in unemployment_data.items():
            date = QDateTime(date).toSecsSinceEpoch()
            print(date, value)
            self.unemployment_chart.append(date, value)
        chart2 = QChart()
        chart2.setTitle('Unemployment')
        chart2.addSeries(self.unemployment_chart)
#        chart2.createDefaultAxes()
        chartView2 = QChartView(chart2)
        grid_box.addWidget(chartView2, 0, 1)
        # Formatting for Date / DateTime Data
        axis_x = QDateTimeAxis()
        axis_x.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        axis_x.setTitleText("Date")
        chart2.setAxisX(axis_x)
        self.unemployment_chart.attachAxis(axis_x)
```

Comment: looking at editing the Series now

Comment: calling legend.hide shouldnt make the axis disappear

Comment: it seems to be working now, not sure why it was not before. thanks

Comment: @Alexander I might have been using close instead with some weird calls.